# JavaScript Error Coding

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues with my homework assignment. I don't know how to start it or how to do it. I don't need the entire code just what is needed for what is being asked. Please can anyone help me on this. I need it ASAP.

> Write a custom error handling JavaScript function called processErrors that handles a custom error by assigning it to the onerror event handler. Include the block of JavaScript statements needed to pass the arguments sent by the JavaScript interpreter into the processErrors function, send an alert message with the agreements, return, and write the event handler that calls the processErrors function.

Please can anyone help me.

```
function handler (processErrors); { onerror="alert ('There was a custom error')"}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a function?  Do you know how to assign a variable?  Do you know how to send an alert message?  Have you not tried *anything*?

Comment: You should provide information on what you have tried so far, including any code that you may have up to this point.

Answer (score 3):

This type of stuff can be a bit challenging when you are completely new to it, so Ill help.  In an html page, put something like the following

```
<script>
  function handler(event) { 
     alert(event);
  }
</script>
```

note that example is not complete according to your question.  what this does is declare a js function, 'handler', that takes an argument, 'event', and then pops up the event.  This is done is 'script' tags, which you should also expand according to your research.

The next thing you will have to do is assign the function defined above that you complete, to the onerror event of some dom, as shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp

Look here for more guidance on js.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

You also might want to google things like: "html script tags" and "javascript event handlers"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide me another example to get me closer to what I am looking for because we really don't need the entire <script> statement just the part for the question.

Comment: im pretty sure you need the script tag, in one form or another.

Comment: @Eman - This is more than enough information for you to work with. Please put some effort into this yourself.

Comment: This is what I have came up with, but I don't know if I am right.

Comment: @john, exactly.  Although, I remember how hard it was to get started when I didn't know things...

Comment: @eman, nothing came through -- you should update your question with what you have come up with.

Comment: function processErrors;  onerror="alert('There was a custom error')"  as well as function processErrors; onerror="DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE" alert("There was a custom error")   Did I do it right please tell me which is correct and how should I wright it. Thank you

Comment: did you get anything? did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: This is the question. 2. Write a custom error handling JavaScript function called processErrors that handles a custom error by assigning it to the onerror event handler. Include the block of JavaScript statements needed to pass the arguments sent by the JavaScript interpreter into the processErrors function, send an alert message with the agreements, return, and write the event handler that calls the processErrors function.

Comment: @eman, you need to update your original question with that code

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote the codes that I came up with and this is the question.

Comment: @eman, you need to calm down.  we are trying to help you.  put your code in your question, please, and format it.

Comment: Is this correct? function handler (processErrors); {       onerror="alert ('There was a custom error')"}

Comment: 2. Write a custom error handling JavaScript function called processErrors that handles a custom error by assigning it to the onerror event handler. Include the block of JavaScript statements needed to pass the arguments sent by the JavaScript interpreter into the processErrors function, send an alert message with the agreements, return, and write the event handler that calls the processErrors function.      function handler (processErrors); { onerror="alert ('There was a custom error')"}

Comment: @eman, look how i edited the original question -- are my words not clear?

Comment: John are you still there. The #2 is the question

Comment: The problem is I can't seem to place it correctly because everytime I press enter it displays the comment before I finish.

Comment: @Eman - Read hvgotcodes's answer **CAREFULLY**. The information you need is in there. Not to mention you have the entire internet at your disposal. There are tons of code examples out there you can learn from. You also might want to google things like: "html script tags" and "javascript event handlers".